# EAGLE Names not showing up on board after footprint update

Tags: pcb, components, eaglecad, layout

I added the >NAME attribute to the footprint of a device and now the names are not shown on the board.

I have already tried to update the library (with library --> update all) and also the replace function.

But when I place the same part again the name is shown, only the old ones wont update, even with the replace function the names are still not shown.

Comment: CTRL-click on all the parts affected (to select all) and use the replace function to apply to all parts selected.

Comment: @Andyaka Like I said, the replace function is not working, doesn't matter if I select one by one or as a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found the answer myself.

When the REPOSITION tool is selected, click on the parts where the name is missing and then the name shows up. Also when a group is selected it's working, just right click and Reposition:Group.

More infos about the problem can be found here: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/changes-made-to-gt-name-in-footprint-not-propagating-from/m-p/8557215/highlight/true#M20265

Answer (score 0):

Click in the scematic or layout editor on Library -> update all

Comment: That is what  I have tried first. It is not working for the Text parts.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. I just tested it and it works for me...